# How to write arithmetic expression to evaluate differentiation in haskell

Tags: haskell

I want the user to enter as Diff x^3 and get the answer as 3x^2

How can I write the arithmetic expression for this evaluation?

What is the best way to do this in haskell?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "write the arithmetic expression"?  Do you just want a toy differentiation engine?  Or are you trying to do something more general?

Comment: I want to built a scientific calculator using haskell.Say if we have the data type data Expr = Val Int
          | Add Expr Expr
          | Mul Expr Expr
we can express the 1+(2*3) as follows Add (Val 1) (Mul (Val 2) (Val 3))
and using a method like this size          :: Expr  Int
size (Val n)   = 1
size (Add x y) = size x + size y
size (Mul x y) = size x * size y  we can do the calculations for th expression.(Got this example from a slide)What I want is to write differentiation expressions like this for easy handling.I tried but I guess I did not get the concept correctly.How can I do that

Comment: Is that possible to do differentiation calculations using arithmetic expressions?Any good tutorials or examples??

Answer (score 5):

Here's an extremely simple version; feel free to extend - add evaluation, several variables, more functions, grouping of terms, pretty printing, parsing etc.

```
data Expr = Const Float | Var | Sum Expr Expr | Product Expr Expr
            deriving Show

diff :: Expr -> Expr
diff (Const _) = Const 0
diff Var = Const 1
diff (Sum f g) = Sum (diff f) (diff g)
diff (Product f g) = Sum (Product f (diff g)) (Product (diff f) g)
```

Comment: Thanks so much.I was trying to work with this example?But I had got some errors.What would be a sample expression that I could use with sum??

Comment: @sunshine: `Sum Var (Const 2)` is x+2; `Sum (Product Var Var) (Product Var (Product Var Var))` is x^2+x^3.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [blog post](http://augustss.blogspot.com/2007/04/overloading-haskell-numbers-part-2.html) that gives a neat way using overloading. Or [here](http://conal.net/blog/posts/beautiful-differentiation/).

Comment: Thanks a lot I will have to look into this deeply.I only have the basic knowledge in haskell.But I really like to make a scientific calculator and include functions for differentiation and other calculations.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic differentiation, as given by supercooldave, is a bit heavyweight for what you want. Better and simpler to start with what you want, sans differentiation -- a way to parse strings into expression trees, to evaluate them, and to show them. Once you have that down, then you just need to code up the chain rule and a few primitives!

Try a simple structure at first like

```
Expr = ENum Double | EVar String | EBinOp BinOp Expr Expr | EUnaryOp UnOp Expr

BinOp = Mul | Add | Div | Pow
UnOp = Diff String | Negate | Abs
```